# Prove equality $ (M \otimes 1_L) \cap (N \otimes_K L) = N$ for inclusion of modules $N \subset M$

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules, galois-theory

Let $K$ be a field, $R$ a Noetherian $K$-algebra
and $M$ some $R$-module. Assume $N \subset M$ is an $R$-submodule. Let $L \supset K$ a finite field extension of $K$ and denote as

$$M_L:= M \otimes_K L$$

(similary for $N_L:=N \otimes_K L$). Note that every $R$-module carries naturally also structure of a $K$-module/ vector space.

Let us choose a concrete finite $K$-basis $k_0:=1_L, k_1,..., k_n$ of $L$. Then we obtain for $M_L$ a decompostion  $M_L= \sum^{n+1}_{i=0} M \otimes_K k_i
\cong M^{n+1}$ as $K$-module which should contain $M $ naturally as
sub-$K$-space via identification $M \cong M \otimes_K 1_L, m \mapsto m \otimes_K 1_L$.

I want to prove the equality

$$  (M \otimes_K 1_L) \cap N_L = N  $$

where $M \otimes_K 1_L $ and $ N_L$ are considered as subspaces of $M_L $ *only by means* of the explicitely described inclusion $ N \subset M \subset M_L $ via the choice
of the $K$-basis of $L$ and it's extension to $M_L $.

The "$\supset $" is trivial inclusion since both subspaces of LHS contain $N$. About
"$\subset $" I not sure if it really so easy as I think or does it contain an important subtility I not see and my "argument" below is wrong:

Let $z \in M \cap (N_L)$. Then $z$ has two expressions, as
$m \cong m \otimes_K 1_L $ and as

$$\sum^{n+1}_{i=0} n_i \otimes_K k_i =
n_0 \otimes_k 1_L + \sum^{n+1}_{i=1} n_i \otimes_K k_i$$

where $m \in M, n_i \in N$.

*Question*: Can we use at that point just the usual "comparison of coefficents" argument known from linear algebra to conclude $m=n_0$ and
$n_i=0$ for $i \neq 0$ to deduce that $z \in N \otimes_K 1_L \cong N$ or it there something going wrong with this "argument"?

Comment: What happens when $M=N\otimes_KL$?

Comment: Then $M$ isn't a $R$-module. Recall that $M$ is assumed to be an $R$-module and (what I forgot to mention in the question) the inclusion $N \subset M$ is considered as an inclusion of $R$-modules

Comment: Isn't there an $R$-action on the first component?

Comment: Oh right, $R$-action only on one component suffice to give $N \otimes L$ an $R$-Mod structure ... yes, that looks like a counterexample...

Comment: @KentaS: But what mistake I make in my "proof"? I not see where I doing something wrong altough your counterexample shows that the claim is wrong.

Comment: @KentaS: after careful consideration I think that 
your example $M:=N \otimes_K L$ isn't a counterexample of 
my claim. The reason is that I missed to explicitely 
spell out how the canonical inclusions $M \subset 
M \otimes_K L$
and $N \otimes_K L\subset M \otimes_K L$  I'm using 
are explicitely given. 
The $M \subset 
M \otimes_K L$ is given canonically by 
$m \mapsto m \otimes_K 1_L$ and $ N \otimes_K L\subset
M \otimes_K L $ 
canonically as well since $N \subset M$ by assumption (I should 
add it in the question).

Comment: Therefore in your example we should be careful how 
to read the a bit misleading notion of the intersection


$$M \cap (N \otimes_K L)$$


Correctly it should we written as
  
$$ (M \otimes_K 1_L) \cap (N \otimes_K L)$$







Then in your example with $M:=N\otimes_K L$ the intersection 
is not identical to $N\otimes_KL$ since we embed $M(:=N \otimes_K L)$ and the intrisical $N \otimes_K L$
as explained above 
in two different ways into $M \otimes_K L$.

Comment: I see, thanks for clearing up the confusion.